# Launch a particular app to download content from webview in Windows8.1

Tags: winrt-xaml, c#-5.0, windows-8.1

I want to lauch in C#
   `UnviewableContentIdentified`
event to download an attachment in email e.g. gmail.
So i wrote another app using *BackgroundDownloader* to download attachment.
But how to launch it when i click on attachment, every time it opens IE metro style.

All i got on internet was **Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri)**
what is URI for a Windows8 app?
Even MSDN community didn't answer it when i asked question there?

Comment: The URI for an application is an URI for an application instead of a website. On Windows Phone 8, the explore-maps://v2.0/show/map/ URI opens the maps application.

Comment: thanks but i just did it in same application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of launching uri I just wrote a `BackgroundDownlaoder` in `Unviewablw` content event.
So no need to launch a second application.